# Access verbosity level in a pytest helper function

Tags: python, pytest

I have a helper function that retrieves a web page from the tested app and converts it to a dict using `json.loads()`. If the page is not a JSON, though, it raises an assertion error.

Now i want my test to print the page data if verbosity is set to 1 or more (ie. i run the tests with `pytest -vv`). I know i can access the config object in tests by using the `config` property of the `request` fixture:

```
def test_use_verbosity(request):
    verbose_level = request.config.getoption('verbose')
```

But how do i access the request in a helper function?

Comment: As `pytest.config` is deprecated, store the config data in a global variable (you can e.g. attach it to a module if it should be importable). You can write a `pytest_configure` hook for that.

Comment: Digging through `pytest` code this seems the only viable option. If you add it as an answer I’ll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `pytest.config` is deprecated, store the config data in a global variable (you can e.g. attach it to a module if it should be importable). You can write a `pytest_configure` hook for that.